# Kill 2 processes with the same name per user by cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Someone who knows how I can kill 2 processes with the same name per user by cmd.

`TASKLIST /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"`

Its like:

```
FOR /f
IF #the user has the program open twice
TASKKILL "PS"
```

Comment: Powershell way: `Get-Process -Name notepad | Stop-Process`. Its actually just `Stop-Process -Name Notepad`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This is tagged `cmd` and `powershell`, are you looking for only `cmd` solutions? Are you trying to kill duplicate processes for a user?

Comment: if it solve the problem, it does not matter it is powershell or cmd

Comment: Have you opened a Command Prompt window, typed `taskkill /?`, and pressed `[ENTER]`? You should note when you do, that there are filters for both `imagename`, and `username`, and examples showing how you may use them. You could additionally, do the same with `tasklist /?`, and/or `qprocess /?`. You may wish to combine your chosen examples from those with pipes and perform the counting using `find /?` or `findstr /?`.

Comment: May be if you use WMIC and filter with command Line ?

Comment: As an expansion of my last comment, and based upon no information from you as to whether you want to close every process, just two, or specific ones, `For /F %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /Fi "UserName Eq Martin" /Fi "ImageName Eq process.exe" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C "."') Do @If %G Gtr 1 %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Fi "UserName Eq Martin" /Im process.exe`. Obviously you'd need to adjust the users name and process name as needed. _Please note however, it probably should not be `cmd.exe`, if the same user is running this command, as it will close itself!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to ***@MC ND's*** Answer here [Kill process in batch file that matches certain name and user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529891/kill-process-in-batch-file-that-matches-certain-name-and-user)

Just test if any line in `tasklist` output passes the two filters, account and executable.

If no process is found, continue

If process is found, anotate it and increment the loop counter

If the limit is reached, kill the process else wait and repeat the process

---

```bat
@ECHO off
Set "MyProcess=wscript.exe"
set "loop=0"
set "loopLimit=2"
:PRVARCHSTART
set "process="
@for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
    'Tasklist /v /fo:csv /nh ^| findstr /l /c:"%username%" ^| findstr /l /c:"%MyProcess%"'
    ) do (
        set /a "loop+=1"
        set "process=%%~a"
)

if not defined process goto :PRVARCHEND

if %loop% geq %loopLimit% (
    Taskkill /pid %process% /f
    goto :PRVARCHEND
)
Ping -n 1 localhost >nul 2>nul
goto :PRVARCHSTART
:PRVARCHEND
pause & Exit
```

---

I have an old vbscript that may be help you to choose what Process you want to kill by its command line !

```
Option Explicit
Dim Titre,Copyright,fso,ws,NomFichierLog,temp,PathNomFichierLog,OutPut,Count
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,_
    "There is an existing proceeding !"
    WScript.Quit
Else 
    Copyright = "[Hackoo "& chr(169) & " 2015]"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = CreateObject( "Wscript.Shell" )
    NomFichierLog="Killed_Process.txt"
    temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%")
    PathNomFichierLog = temp & "\" & NomFichierLog
    Set OutPut = fso.CreateTextFile(temp & "\" & NomFichierLog,1)
    Call Find("wscript.exe")
    Call Find("cmd.exe")
    Call Explorer(PathNomFichierLog)
End If
'***************************************************************************************************
Function Explorer(File)
    Dim ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run "Explorer "& File & "\",1,True
end Function
'***************************************************************************************************
Sub Find(MyProcess)
    Dim colItems,objItem,Processus,Question,Msg
    Titre = " Process(es) "& DblQuote(MyProcess) &" running "
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND NOT commandline like " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "",,48)
    Count = 0 
    For Each objItem in colItems
        Count= Count + 1
        Processus = objItem.CommandLine
        Question = MsgBox ("Would do you like to kill this script : " & DblQuote(Processus) & " ?" ,VBYesNO+VbQuestion,Titre+Copyright)
        If Question = VbYes then
            objItem.Terminate(0)'To kill the process
            OutPut.WriteLine Processus
        else
            Count= Count - 1 'decrementing the count of -1
        End if
    Next
    OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*")
    If Count > 1 Then
        Msg = " were killed"
    Else
        Msg = " was killed"
    End if
    OutPut.WriteLine count & Titre & Msg
    OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*") & VbCrLF 
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "window title" for both of the processes is = "Untitled - Notepad"
The command would be;

taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled - Notepad" /fi "username eq yourusername"

Othervise you need to provide imagename or pid.
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myapp.exe /fi "username eq yourusername"